# not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: hibernate

Facing trouble in saving parent/child object with hibernate. Any idea would be highly appreciated.

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: example.forms.InvoiceItem.invoice
    at org.hibernate.engine.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:100)
        .... (truncated)
```

hibernate mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="example.forms">
    <class name="Invoice" table="Invoices">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="invDate" type="timestamp" />
        <property name="customerId" type="int" />
        <set cascade="all" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="items" order-by="id">
            <key column="invoiceId" />
            <one-to-many class="InvoiceItem" />
        </set>
    </class>
    <class name="InvoiceItem" table="InvoiceItems">
        <id column="id" name="itemId" type="long">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="productId" type="long" />
        <property name="packname" type="string" />
        <property name="quantity" type="int" />
        <property name="price" type="double" />
        <many-to-one class="example.forms.Invoice" column="invoiceId" name="invoice" not-null="true" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

InvoiceManager.java

```
class InvoiceManager {

    public Long save(Invoice theInvoice) throws RemoteException {
        Session session = HbmUtils.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Long id = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(theInvoice);
            tx.commit();
            id = theInvoice.getId();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RemoteException("Invoice could not be saved");
        } finally {
            if (session.isOpen())
                session.close();
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

Invoice.java

```
public class Invoice implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Date invDate;
    private int customerId;
    private Set<InvoiceItem> items;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public Date getInvDate() {
        return invDate;
    }
    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public Set<InvoiceItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    void setInvDate(Date invDate) {
        this.invDate = invDate;
    }
    void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    void setItems(Set<InvoiceItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

InvoiceItem.java

```
public class InvoiceItem implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Long itemId;
    private long productId;
    private String packname;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    private Invoice invoice;

    public Long getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }
    public long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
    public String getPackname() {
        return packname;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public Invoice getInvoice() {
        return invoice;
    }
    void setItemId(Long itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
    void setProductId(long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }
    void setPackname(String packname) {
        this.packname = packname;
    }
    void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    void setInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
        this.invoice = invoice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Every `InvoiceItem` must have an `Invoice` attached to it because of the `not-null="true"` in the *many-to-one* mapping.

So the basic idea is you need to set up that explicit relationship in code.  There are many ways to do that.  On your class I see a `setItems` method.  I do NOT see an `addInvoiceItem` method.  When you set items, you need to loop through the set and call `item.setInvoice(this)` on all of the items.  If you implement an `addItem` method, you need to do the same thing.  Or you need to otherwise set the Invoice of every `InvoiceItem` in the collection.

Answer (score 109):

for followers, this error message can also mean "you have it referencing a foreign object that hasn't been saved to the DB yet" (even though it's there, and is non null).

Comment: And how can I solve this? Example: I have Entity_A with an Entity_B column, and in Entity_B I have an Entity_A column the relation is @OneToMany from A to B and when I try to update Entity_A then gives me this exception, how could I update Entity_A?

Comment: @FAndrew save Entity_B first?

Comment: and if I have for example 100 Entity_B, I search for all edited Entity_B and if it was edited I update it? Wouldn`t be nicer if I just update Entity_A?

Answer (score 14):

This could be as simple as:

```
@Column(name = "Some_Column", nullable = false)
```

but while persisting, the value of "Some_Column"is null, even if "Some_Column" may not be any primary or foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

Check the unsaved values for your primary key/Object ID in your hbm files. If you have automated ID creation by hibernate framework and you are setting the ID somewhere it will throw this error.By default the unsaved value is 0, so if you set the ID to 0 you will see this error.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved by removing    @Basic(optional = false)  property
or
just update boolean    @Basic(optional = true)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in SpringBoot when I incorrectly referred to the SQL column title rather than the entity attribute in the code.

```
@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
private String firstName;
```

Refer to this as `firstName` when making the request.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error but solved it finally,actually i was not setting the Object Entity which is already saved to the other entity and hence the Object value it was getting for foreeign key was null.

Answer (score 0):

My case, I have _menu tabel. _manu is used to store dashboard menu where it has menu_parent. So the relation is to itself.

Let say we have _menu:

```
Id Name             menu_parent
1  User Management  null
```

because **User Management**'s menu_parent is null, it is called parent menu. Let make the child menu:

```
Id Name             menu_parent
2  User Edit        1
3  User Other       1
```

**User Edit** and **User Other** are the children of **Menu Management**.
Thus, the relation is Many To One.

This our old code:

```
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "menu_parent", nullable = true)
private Menu menuParent;
```

You see, it used OneToOne, even nullable = true.
The error:

```
not-null property references a null or transient value: com.va.core.entity.role.Menu.menuParent; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.va.core.entity.role.Menu.menuParent
```

My solution is just changing the relation to ManyToOne as below:

```
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "menu_parent", nullable = true)
private Menu menuParent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.graphql.graphql.entity
```

I got this error in graphql with spring boot

the problem I was add new row to database table class but I forget to set the values for the columns

that's was the wrong function in entity class (database table)

```
public Dog(String name, String modal, String breed) {
}
```

while name and modal are not null so when it return the newDog class it has this error because I'm not saving the values so everything was null while it except values in (not null columns) which are name, modal so I solved it like that in the entity table class

```
    public Dog(String name, String modal, String breed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.modal = modal;
        this.breed = breed;
    }
```

#### also I forget to add the setter and getter in the Dog table and added them

so this flag means the class returned has null values for columns that not accept null or (all columns returned was null in my case and when `addNewDog` all values was null)

eg what java saw while first two columns are `nullable=false`

```
    class Dog{
      # not null column
      String name = null;
      
      # not null column
      String modal = null;

      String breed = null;
    }
```

now the newDog class returned has the values for columns that not accept null and problem solved

please note this solution to describe and solve the error message itself

Answer (score 0):

For me the error occured because I did not set correctly the One-to-Many relation of the newly created objects.

For example saving a new school with lots of students in it: School -> Student

```
SchoolEntity school = new SchoolEntity();

List<Students> studens = new ArrayList<>();
Student a = new Student();
Student b = new Student();

students.forEach(e -> e.setSchool(school)); // missing this step will cause the error
school.setStudents(students);
schoolRepository.save(school);
```

Answer (score -1):

add @EnableJpaAuditing annotation in your main class

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the identical error while attempting to save a record. The error occurred because I had omitted the correct request body, resulting in an attempt to save a null value in a column designated as non-nullable. To resolve this, I successfully rectified the issue by modifying the request body of the PostRequest.

Answer (score -3):

```
cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST
```

I think it will help.