# Set Date to null in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, date, annotations, persistence

I have problems to set the DATE to null info from my Oracle DB.

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "LAST_DATE", nullable = false, unique = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)    
private Date lastDate;
```

When I set `lastDate` in to null and try to execute insert or update query I get exception
*org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [not-null property references a null or transient value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389600/not-null-property-references-a-null-or-transient-value)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `nullable = false` from `@Column` annotation. Or you can set `nullable = true`.

Comment: I changed annotation, but it still doesn't work.                @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "LAST_DATE", nullable =true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)    
    private Date lastDate;

Comment: You might also need to change it in database table, where you have mentioned it as Not Null while creating table.

Comment: Rahul, thank you your help. When I created database I set not null option for column "LAST_DATE". Afteyor recomendation it doesn't woked. I removed record "@Basic(optional = false)". Now my query work correctly.