# Spring tool suite: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

could you help me with this question?

I built a project on sts4. I am trying to let users register an account on Postman. The primary method I am testing is Put(PutMapping), which I wrote on sts4. I got the project initialized completely, but when I click send from Postman, I got errors like below.

`not-null property references a null or transient value: com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.io.entity.UserEntity.firstName`

The following is part of my project.

1. UserDetailsRequestModel, (for processing incoming requestbody)

````
public class UserDetailsRequestModel {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstName = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastName = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}```

2. UserRest, (Class, which will be returned back to Postman)


```package com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.ui.model.response;

public class UserRest {

    // public id, not auto increment key from database
    private String userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}```

3. UserDTO

```package com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.shared.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5607842248454975055L;
    // auto increment key from database
    private long id;
    // public user id, which could be returned back to application
    private String userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    // clear text password
    private String password;
    // password which is encrypted, stored,
    private String encryptedPassword;
    private String emailVerificationToken;
    private Boolean emailVerificationStatus = false;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEncryptedPassword() {
        return encryptedPassword;
    }

    public void setEncryptedPassword(String encryptedPassword) {
        this.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
    }

    public String getEmailVerificationToken() {
        return emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationToken(String emailVerificationToken) {
        this.emailVerificationToken = emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public Boolean getEmailVerificationStatus() {
        return emailVerificationStatus;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationStatus(Boolean emailVerificationStatus) {
        this.emailVerificationStatus = emailVerificationStatus;
    }

}
````

4. UserEntity

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name = "users")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5313493413859894403L;

    // this Id is a primary key and auto incremented
    // once a new record is inserted into database table
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 120)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String encryptedPassword;

    private String emailVerificationToken;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean emailVerificationStatus = false;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEncryptedPassword() {
        return encryptedPassword;
    }

    public void setEncryptedPassword(String encryptedPassword) {
        this.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
    }

    public String getEmailVerificationToken() {
        return emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationToken(String emailVerificationToken) {
        this.emailVerificationToken = emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public Boolean getEmailVerificationStatus() {
        return emailVerificationStatus;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationStatus(Boolean emailVerificationStatus) {
        this.emailVerificationStatus = emailVerificationStatus;
    }

}
```

5. UserServiceImpl

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.UserRepository;
import com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.io.entity.UserEntity;
import com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.service.UserService;
import com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.shared.dto.UserDTO;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;  

    @Override
    public UserDTO createUser(UserDTO user) { 

        // (0) check whether the email already exist in database
        if(userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Email already exists.");
        }

        // 1. create an object UserEntity, 
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();

        // 2. copy info from userDTO to userEntity
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, userEntity);

        // 3. encryptedPassword can't be got from user
        // we have to assign value here for testing
        userEntity.setEncryptedPassword("test");

        // 4. the second data that is generated during this class is userID
        userEntity.setUserId("testUserId");

        // 5. now we can save userEntity into database,
        // since it contains info from user, have to use userRepository
        // after Auto-wired, we can use its methods
        // use save method, we can save userEntity into database
        UserEntity storedUserDetails = userRepository.save(userEntity);

        // 6. we can return it back to RestController
        // so we need an UserDTO object
        UserDTO returnValue = new UserDTO();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(storedUserDetails, returnValue);

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

6. UserController

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.service.UserService;
import com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.shared.dto.UserDTO;
import com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.ui.model.request.UserDetailsRequestModel;
import com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.ui.model.response.UserRest;

@RestController // to make this class receive requests from HTTP
@RequestMapping("users") // http://localhost:8080/users + methods
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping
    public String getUser() {
        return "get user was called";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public UserRest createUser(@RequestBody UserDetailsRequestModel userDetails) {

        // 1. instantiate a new object, which will be returned.
        UserRest returnValue = new UserRest();

        System.out.println(userDetails.getFirstname());

        // 2. instantiate a new User Data transfer object, 
        // which could be shared across different layers
        // we will populate this object with info we received from request body
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();

        // 3. use class BeanUtils class, which is from spring framework
        // to copy properties from source object(userDetails) to our data transfer object
        // so, we can populate info from request body into our data transfer object
        // so, we have a data transfer object, which is populated info from request body
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDetails, userDTO);

        // 4. 
        // (1) userDTO, will be created at UI level, then be passed to service layer
        // (2) service class will perform some additional business logic
        //   and generate some additional values, these values will be added to userDTO, 
        // (3) then userDTO will be used in business logic with a data layer 
        //   to prepare an entity class, which will be stored in database
        UserDTO createdUser = userService.createUser(userDTO);

        // 5. populate returnValue object
        // copy information from createdUser into returnValue
        // other sensitive info, like password, should not be included
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(createdUser, returnValue);

        // 6. return, to mobile applications，or in here to Postman(HTTP client)
        return returnValue;
    }

    @PutMapping
    public String updateUser() {
        return "update user was called";
    }

    @DeleteMapping
    public String deleteUser() {
        return "delete user was called";
    }

}
```

7. Configuration on Postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd0DA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l55wd.png)

8. The Error I got

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIXi7.png)

I spent a day on it. Help, please.

Comment: Did you check data properly copied in `userEntity` before call `userRepository.save(userEntity)` ?

Comment: Please do provide exceptions as text formatted as code, not as images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [not-null property references a null or transient value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389600/not-null-property-references-a-null-or-transient-value)

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you for helping.

Comment: I tried to delete all setters and getters on UserRequestModel. And then rebuild them again, problem solved. Although I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@PutMapping
    public String updateUser(@RequestBody) {
        return "update user was called";
    }
```